# Glyphicon Bootstrap v3 Not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I downloaded the latest Bootstrap v3 file and imported bootstrap.min.css. But I never be able to use the Glyphicon Icons.
I'm pretty sure that my CSS is right. 
Below is my HTML. Why?

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the path to `fonts` is correct. The definition in boostrap.min.css looks like this:

```
[..] url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')
```

Comment: Where do you get this eot file? and where do I import it in?

Comment: It's in the downloaded file (dist/fonts)

Comment: How do I import those downloaded (font) file?

Comment: Just place them in the corret folde, bootstrap.min.css will import them for you. If you download from http://getbootstrap.com/ they will be in the archive.

Comment: My font folder is already at the same level as CSS. It does not work. How can I change the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap usually includes three main folders i.e. CSS, Fonts & JS. Missing or wrong replacement of 'Fonts' folder creates problems in displaying bootstrap glyphicons. See another similar question [Bootstrap loading wrong glyphicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583025/bootstrap-loading-wrong-glyphicon)