# Angular bootstrap-ui, glyphicons not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use bootstrap-ui to with my angular project.  I am using Bootstrap V2.2.2.  Originally I kept getting a `404 Not Found` error for my glyphicons.  I downloaded the glyphicons and placed them in my img  folder.  I now do not get an error, but they do not show up on the page.  Everything else is working fine, I get no errors, but the images are not showing.  Has anyone else had to deal with this issue?  What is the resolution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421340/glyphicon-bootstrap-v3-not-loaded/19421372#19421372

Comment: My bootstrap.css is not looking for an `.eot` file, it is looking for a `.png`, `background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png")` and it is finding it.

Comment: If you navigate to the url in your browser, can you see it?

Comment: The document is there, but it shows me the icon, like an image is supposed to be there, but it isn't.  What would cause that?

Comment: B Cotter, you were right.  I created an empty document, so it was showing nothing, just like I told it to.  Create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Download Zip on the GitHub page. Open the zip and copy the Fonts folder to the same folder as your html file. Bootstrap UI should now find the glyph fonts.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap